# Как сказать скрипту чтоб он дождлася загрузки другого скрипта?

Tags: javascript

В конце страницы подключен скрипт `app.js`. В этом файле есть такой код:

```
const url = window.location.search.slice(5);

function addScript(src){
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `db/${src}`;
    script.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

addScript(url);

console.log(data);
```

Таким способом я подключаю к странице `json` файл, не спрашивайте почему я его так подключаю и почему я не сделаю через `fetch`. В этом `json` файле есть переменная `data` которой я присваиваю все данные из файла. Я пробовал подключить просто сам файл к странице, то переменная `data` существует. А когда через скрипт добавляю и пытаюсь вывести `data` в консоль то пишет, что `data is not defined`. Подскажите что нужно сделать, что выполнилось сначала подключение, а потом остальной код. Пробовал обернуть `console.log(data)` в событие `DOMContentLoaded`, не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const url = window.location.search.slice(5);

function addScript(src, data){

    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `db/${src}`;
    script.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    return data()

}

addScript(url, () => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: оо, интересное решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Либо можеш использовать Promise(), либо конструкцию async await, либо setTimeOut(), это все для работы с асинхронными функциями)

Comment: Ну вот setTimeout я попробовал, работало, но я подумал, что это как-тот не правильно. И пробовал через async await, но не получилось. Можете пожалуйста привести еще пример с async await? Чтоб разобраться в этом, ибо у меня часто возникают такие случаи